# Alternatives to RFID - RUBEE

Tags: communication, arm, rfid

Since RFID tag reading has poor performance in adverse weather conditions, I've received advice to use RUBEE. But I could not find it being implemented, nor available on a consumer scale. i.e., RFID tag, tag reader etc are readily available in the market. But I could not find any single one for RUBEE.

Even if I'm pursuing after RFID, I have a doubt on its performance at high speed. For example, if the reader is installed in a fast moving vehicle, say 75 mph, can it practically read a stationary tag on the side of the road? If it can't, what may be possible alternatives that function well in such a situation?

Comment: The RFID performance is mostly related to distance.  Even in a rain storm, you can talk to your backscatter tags.  RFID is also just a "blanket" term.  You'll find that the lower frequency tags work very well in the rain.  The low kHz tags will even work under centimeters of water.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: using RFID tag system at high speeds (either reader or tag at relatively high speed).. i mean. will it work?

Comment: I don't see why not, particularly in a space that's not too crowded.    Ultimately, it'll depend on how long communication takes and the ISO-18000-C spec will give you commercial timings.  If you don't have collisions, I do not see why an Impinj tag and reader won't work at 100m/s   Get the Impinj demo setup and go for a drive in the rain.  In an actual implementation, you will want to have a high gain antenna, like the tolling on the motorways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a problem with weather, or speed for a standard RFID tag, and I believe that even a passive-tag will work well enough to get to the Query command.  I've attached the timing for a Query and simple response with decomposition of the waveform so that you can reference them in the [EPC Global Gen2 specification](http://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/uhfc1g2_2_0_0_standard_20131101.pdf) for the commercial, off the shelf, tags.  You can accomplish the identification in 420uS, but not much else.

[image]

The carrier wave that charges the tag will be the wildcard, and you need 1mS for many systems.  I'm sure that Impinj or Alien or NXP will have some more data on this.